# Proving existence of a linear transformation with given properties

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The question is as follows:

> Suppose that $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $3$. Fix a non-zero vector $v\in V$ and define
>   $$U:=\{T\in\mathcal{L}(V):v\mbox{ is and eigenvector of }T\}.$$
>   Now fix an arbitrary basis $B$ of $V$. Show that there is a nonzero linear transformation $S\in U$ such that
>   $$\mathcal{M}(S,B)=\begin{bmatrix}a&a&c\\b&a&c\\b&b&c\end{bmatrix}.$$

Note that the notation $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is used to denote the linear operators on $V$ and $\mathcal{M}(S,B)$ is the matrix of $S$ with respect to $B$. I'm not sure if this notation is conventional or not, and it's probably clear from context...

I am able to show that $U$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{L}(V)$ of dimension $7$, but beyond that I'm not sure how to approach this. I know a nonconstructive solution exists, but I keep finding myself actually trying to compute values of $a,b,c$ (which is a poor approach even without knowledge of a nonconstructive solution, since the basis is arbitrarily chosen). This is a homework question, so I am requesting hints, not a full solution.

Comment: I think you are meant to use that 7+3>9. 3 being the dimension of space of matrices of the form M and 9 being the dimension of space of all matrices

Comment: @user25959 Ha! It's obvious when you see it. Pigeonhole principle. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Here is the solution presented in the comments below. My original solution is after this.

Note that $\dim V\ge\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)$. Let $W$ be the subspace of linear operators with matrices of the form of $M$. Then since $\dim V=9$, $\dim U=7$, and $\dim W=3$, it follows that $\dim(U\cap W)\ge1$. The desired result follows.

---

Observe that the dimension of the space of linear operators with matrices of the form of $M$ (with respect to $B$) is $3$. Since the dimension of the full space of $3\times3$ matrices is $9$, and $\mbox{dim }U=7$, by the pigeonhole principle, the desired result follows.

Comment: It isn't pigeonhole principle, but a consequence of $\dim V\ge\dim(U+W)=\dim U+\dim W-\dim(U\cap W)$. Put $\dim V=9, \dim U=7$ and $\dim W=3$, we get $\dim(U\cap W)\ge1$.

Comment: @user1551 Your argument that the intersection of the spaces must be non-zero is effectively the same as saying you have 10 pigeons and only 9 pigeonholes, is it not?

Comment: How? Please define your "pigeons" and "pigeonholes" rigourously. You seem to be bending a simple dimension argument into one using the pigeonhole principle. This of course can be done technically, but I would say that's a very contrived way to disguise a technical detail as a hand wavy, "intuitive"-looking argument that sounds familiar to the laymen.

Comment: @user1551 I don't see how it's hand wavy. We have a vector space of dimension $9$, a subspace of dimension $7$, and another subspace of dimension $3$...these subspaces *must* intersect.

Comment: @user1551 That's where the pigeonhole principle arises. If they didn't intersect, then we would somehow have $10$ dimensions hiding inside a $9$ dimensional space.

Comment: This is what I mean by "hand wavy" --- what exactly do you mean by having *"10 dimensions hiding inside a 9 dimensional space"*? A dimension is not a member of a vector space. Would you please explain your idea using the language of the [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)?

Comment: @user1551 Suppose, for contradiction, that there does not exist an $S$ with the desired properties. It is clear that the subspace of matrices of the given form has dimension $3$. That is, there exists a basis $(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ of this subspace. Similarly, there exists a basis $(w_1,\cdots,w_7)$ of $U$. Then by assumption, $(v_1,\cdots,v_3,w_1,\cdots,w_7)$ is a linearly independent list. This, however, implies that $\mbox{dim }\mathcal{L}(V)=10$, a contradiction. Using the desired language, the full space has $m=9$ containers and the subspaces have a total of $n=10$ items (basis vectors)

Comment: Have to agree with @user1551 (i.e. inclusion-exclusion principle is the proper argument) but maybe not their tone.  You didn't justify your line "by assumption, etc is a linearly independent list".  Certainly, it is true that if nonzero $S$ exists, then $(v_1,\ldots,w_7)$ is linearly dependent. The line I quoted from you is the inverse statement. It is true too but not immediately obvious. (Try if you don't believe me: prove that if $S$ doesn't exist, then that set of 10 vectors is linearly independent - it echoes the proof of inclusion-exclusion)

Comment: @user25959 Why is it not clear that $(v_1,\cdots,w_7)$ is linearly independent? If the subspaces don't intersect, then their bases must be linearly independent to one another, right? My claim is that assuming such an $S$ doesn't exist leads to an absurdity, so it must be the case that such an $S$ does exist.

Comment: That is right, but again, if you write out a proof of that statement carefully you essentially re-prove the inclusion-exclusion principle.